# DisplayAlert is not working when defined in non event handler method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to show the Alert dialog to the user. I am trying to achieve this by defining a method in the code-behind(About.xaml.cs) class and calling it from ViewModel(myViewModel.cs) class. But this is not working. DisplayAlert is working fine in other event handler methods.

**About.xaml.cs**

```
public void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayAlert("hello", "test", "Yes", "No"); //working
    RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
    gender = rb.Content as string;
}

public async Task<bool> DisplayConfirmation(string title, string msg)
{
    return await DisplayAlert(title, msg, "Yes", "No");  //not working
}
```

**myViewModel.cs**

```
async void deleteStudentRecord(int id)
{
    About about = new About();
    if (await about.DisplayConfirmation("Alert!", "Are you sure?")) 
    {
         try
         {
             int deleted_count = await DBServices.DeleteRecord(id);
             await Refresh();
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
         }
    }             
}
```

It will be very helpful if someone explains this behavior and show the right method to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Like Below using App Context,

```
Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("hello", "test", "Yes", "No")
```

Thanks